# How can I delay the upload of an image to S3?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, dropzone

I am working on an "uploadProductPage", where I can input some data that gets saved in mongoDB and upload a photo that is uploaded to Amazon S3. I am using dropzone for the image uploading process, and when I select a file, it instantly uploads to S3. I would like to delay the uploading process until pressing the "submit" button, if possible.

My code is as follows:

fileUpload.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';
import { Icon } from 'antd';
import Axios from 'axios';
import download from './download.jpeg'
  
  
function FileUpload(props) {
  
      const [Images, setImages] = useState([])
  
      const onDrop = (files) => {
  
      let formData = new FormData();
          const config = {
              header: {
                  'accept': 'application/json',
                  'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
                  'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${formData._boundary}`
              }
          }
          formData.append("profileImage", files[0])
          //save the Image we chose inside the Node Server 
          Axios.post('/api/photo/profile-img-upload', formData, config)
              .then(response => {
                if (response.data) {
                    alert('Saved')
                    setImages([...Images, response.data.imageName])
                    props.refreshFunction([...Images, response.data.image])

                } else {
                    alert('Failed to save the Image in Server')
                }
            })
    }


    const onDelete = (image) => {
        const currentIndex = Images.indexOf(image);

        let newImages = [...Images]
        newImages.splice(currentIndex, 1)

        setImages(newImages)
        props.refreshFunction(newImages)
    }

    return (
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
            <Dropzone
                onDrop={onDrop}
                multiple={false}
                maxSize={800000000}
            >
                {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
                    <div style={{
                        width: '300px', height: '240px', border: '1px solid lightgray',
                        display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'
                    }}
                        {...getRootProps()}
                    >
                        {console.log('getRootProps', { ...getRootProps() })}
                        {console.log('getInputProps', { ...getInputProps() })}
                        <input {...getInputProps()} />
                        <Icon type="plus" style={{ fontSize: '3rem' }} />

                    </div>
                )}
            </Dropzone>

            <div style={{ display: 'flex', width: '300px', height: '300px'}}>

                {Images.map((image, index) => (
                    <div onClick={() => onDelete(image)}>
                        <img style={{ minWidth: '300px', width: '300px', height: '240px' }} src={download} alt={`productImg-${index}`} />
                    </div>
                ))}


            </div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default FileUpload
```

photo.js (router)

```
const express = require( 'express' );
const multer = require('multer');
const url = require('url');
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const multerS3 = require("multer-s3");
const { auth } = require("../middleware/auth");
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();


const s3 = new aws.S3({
    accessKeyId: '',
    secretAccessKey: '',
    Bucket: 'uploads-111'
});

aws.config.update({
    secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_ACCESS_SECRET,
    accessKeyId: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: "us-east-2",
  });

  const profileImgUpload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
     s3: s3,
     bucket: 'uploads-111',
     acl: 'public-read',
     key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, path.basename( file.originalname, path.extname( file.originalname ) ) + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname( file.originalname ) )
     }
    }),
    limits:{ fileSize: 2000000 }, // In bytes: 2000000 bytes = 2 MB
    fileFilter: function( req, file, cb ){
     checkFileType( file, cb );
    }
   }).single('profileImage');

function checkFileType(file, cb) {
    // Allowed ext
    const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;
    // Check ext
    const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
    // Check mime
    const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);
    if (mimetype && extname) {
        return cb(null, true);
    } else {
        cb('Error: Images Only!');
    }

if( mimetype && extname ){
    return cb( null, true );
   } else {
    cb( 'Error: Images Only!' );
   }
}

    router.post( '/profile-img-upload', ( req, res ) => {
    profileImgUpload( req, res, ( error ) => {
        // console.log( 'requestOkokok', req.file );
        // console.log( 'error', error );
        if( error ){
         console.log( 'errors', error );
         res.json( { error: error } );
        } else {
         // If File not found
         if( req.file === undefined ){
          console.log( 'Error: No File Selected!' );
          res.json( 'Error: No File Selected' );
         } else {
          // If Success
          const imageName = req.file.key;
          const imageLocation = req.file.location;
          res.json( {
            image: imageName,
            location: imageLocation
           } );
          }
         }
        });
       });

module.exports = router;
```

uploadProductPage.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Typography, Button, Form, message, Input, Icon } from 'antd';
import FileUpload from '../../utils/FileUpload'
import Axios from 'axios';

const { Title } = Typography;
const { TextArea } = Input;

 
const Continents = [
    { key: 1, value: "1" },
    { key: 2, value: "2" },
    { key: 3, value: "3" },
    { key: 4, value: "4" },
    { key: 5, value: "5" },
    { key: 6, value: "6" },
    { key: 7, value: "7" }
]


function UploadProductPage(props) {

    const [TitleValue, setTitleValue] = useState("")
    const [DescriptionValue, setDescriptionValue] = useState("")
    const [PriceValue, setPriceValue] = useState(0)
    const [ContinentValue, setContinentValue] = useState([])

    const [Images, setImages] = useState([])


    const onTitleChange = (event) => {
        setTitleValue(event.currentTarget.value)
    }

    const onDescriptionChange = (event) => {
        setDescriptionValue(event.currentTarget.value)
    }

    const onPriceChange = (event) => {
        setPriceValue(event.currentTarget.value)
    }

    const onContinentsSelectChange = (event) => {
        setContinentValue(event.currentTarget.value)
    }

    const updateImages = (newImages) => {
        setImages(newImages)
    }
    const onSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();


        if (!TitleValue || !DescriptionValue || !PriceValue ||
            !ContinentValue || !Images) {
            return alert('fill all the fields first!')
        }

        const variables = {
            writer: props.user.userData._id,
            title: TitleValue,
            description: DescriptionValue,
            price: PriceValue,
            images: Images,
            continents: ContinentValue,
        }

        Axios.post('/api/product/uploadProduct', variables)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data.success) {
                    alert('Product Successfully Uploaded')
                    props.history.push({
                        pathname: "/user/cart",
                        state: {
                          data: variables,
                        }, 
                      })
                } else {
                    alert('Failed to upload Product')
                }
            })

    }

    return (
        <div style={{ maxWidth: '700px', margin: '2rem auto' }}>
            <div style={{ textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: '2rem' }}>
                <Title level={2}> Upload Prompt </Title>
            </div>


            <Form onSubmit={onSubmit} >

                {/* DropZone */}
                <FileUpload refreshFunction={updateImages} />

                <br />
                <br />
                <label>Subject</label>
                <Input
                    onChange={onTitleChange}
                    value={TitleValue}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label>Title</label>
                <Input
                    onChange={onDescriptionChange}
                    value={DescriptionValue}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label>Pages</label>
                <Input
                    onChange={onPriceChange}
                    value={PriceValue}
                    type="number"
                />
                <br /><br />
                <label>Due Date</label>
                <br /><br />
                <Input onChange={onContinentsSelectChange} value={ContinentValue}
                    type="date"
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <Button
                    onClick={onSubmit}
                >
                    Submit
                </Button>
            </Form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default UploadProductPage
```

Comment: You need to remove the the code from onDrop function where you are posting it to backend in your fileUpload.js file. send image when you are clicking on submit button.

Comment: how would i add the on submit part to the code?